# Why the browser is commenting out my php code

Tags: php

I am having a weird problem. I have a database (my_db) and I connected to the data base using PDO and successfully tested the connection. Afterward, I created a file with a name 'get_users.php' like the following

```
<?php
    require '../db/connect.inc.php'; 

    $query = "SELECT * FROM users WHERE role = '0'";
    $result = $handler->query($query);
    while ($row = $result->fetch()) {
        echo $row['first_name'];
    }
?>
```

I tried to test the query by navigating to the php file that has this query and it echoed all the workers first name.

Finally, In my index.html file. I tried the following

`<?php include 'services/get_users.php'; ?>` but it did not work. I thought that my path is wrong, however, when I tried to inspect the page I saw my php code like that `<!-- <?php include 'services/get_users.php'; -->?>`

Why the browser is commenting out my php code. PHP is a server side, I must not be able to see any php tag.

Thank you!!

Comment: You need to call the file index.php, not .html maybe?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your file extension is `.html` then the PHP interpreter will not read the code. You will want to save your index file as `index.php` with the `.php` extension for the interpreter to read it.

Comment: you're right.. it was a stupid mistake.. thank you all

Comment: if this solved your question, you should accept his anwer @Riad

Comment: Just to point out this isn't always true. Any extension can be used, PHP doesn't actually care, but web servers do as they need to know what to send to the interpreter. More often than not, it's limited to `.php` and alike, but it's not guaranteed.

Comment: @Jon is correct, I decided not to go into that since I knew he was using a web server with, probably, minimal configuration. You can read more [here](https://www.rssinclude.com/blog/36_how_to_run_php_scripts_in_html_or_htm_files)

Answer (score 0):

If you want. Html files to be executed as Php then you have edit htpdconfig file Apache where you may add any extension. 
Note:- For security point of view you should not do so,  it may lead to execution of arbitrary php  code.  You should use. Php extension.  You can also rewrite url by which your users will see `*.html` or `*.Nothing` ininstead  of *.php`.  {{ i am on mobile right now,  i will update with code soon}}

Comment: Thank you Ravinder